# odoo many2many show selection Odoo10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

we have a list of items in one model named us_inventory_line. We have another model named ladings...

```py
class inventory_line(models.Model):
    # ...
    lading_item = fields.Many2one('res.lading', ondelete='set null', string="lading", index=True)

class Lading(models.Model):
    # ... 
    us_inventory_line_item = fields.One2many(comodel_name='rodals.us_inventory_line', string="shippments", inverse_name='lading_item')
```

In the form, we have just simply put the field that represent one2many:

```xml
<!-- Form -->
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="us_inventory_line_form_view">
    <field name="name">lading.form</field>
    <field name="model">rodals.lading</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Invetory Line Form">
            <sheet>
                <group>
                    <field name="delivery_date"/>
                    <field name="us_inventory_line_item"/>
                </group>
            </sheet>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>
```

When the application is opened, when the user opens the lading page, he is only able to add new us_inventory_line.

How do we go about in order to connect the tow ? Like the user need to choose, from a list of us_inventory_line that does not have a lading (because if its has lading, this means that its already shipped).

Thank you very much for the help !

Answer (score 0):

```
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="us_inventory_line_form_view">
    <field name="name">lading.form</field>
    <field name="model">rodals.lading</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Invetory Line Form">
            <sheet>
                 <group>
                     <field name="delivery_date"/>
                     <field name="us_inventory_line_item">
                        <tree string="US Inventory Item">
                           <field name="lading_item"/>
                        </tree>
                     </field>
                 </group>
             </sheet>
         </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Comment: This will show only inventory_lines that does not yet been associated with a lading ? Thank you Again.